# I changed my email address twice and still need to use my old address to log in

Tags: support, login, email, email-addresses

I used an old email address from a provider that is long dead now, so when I logged in stackoverflow, I clicked on my name, got into "emails" settings and changed the address in two different locations (first time i changed the email only in one field and then couldnt log in, so I verified and changed another field)

But guess what? I still can't use my changed email, even if it's listed in that profile.

I'm lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your goal is to be able to sign in with that newer email, but you're finding you can't, right?

It sounds like you're changing your contact email [on your Email Settings page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/email/settings/current), but this does not change your login credentials.

You can manage your login credentials at [the My Logins page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current) in your preferences. Add your new credentials there. You will then be able to sign in with those new credentials.

Comment: Ok thank you! so I added another login by connecting with my email (i'm sure 80% of the people wouldn't have found how to proceed and even more wouldn't have found the link until you pointed it to me). Now it says " Stack Exchange Stack Exchange (used 8 mins ago) change password   remove" But it doesn't list my email, this is utterly confusing because the other line show my old email

Comment: it's normal, right?

Comment: My Stack Exchange account entry shows my email, but you might want to ask about that in a separate question.